# StorageFolder GetFolderFromPathAsync throws Value does not fall within the expected range error

Tags: c#, uwp, storagefile, storagefolder

I am trying to open a FileSaveDialog and when the user presses save, I am creating a zip in the LocalFolder and moving it over to the user selected location. With this code, the file successfully moves to the selected location, but I get an exception like 'Value does not fall within the expected range error.' when I say `var storageFolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(localfile.Path);` Please help.

Here is the full code.

```
public async Task<bool> WriteFilesToFolder(string baseFolderName, Dictionary<string, string> contentOfFilesWithFileNames)
        {
            try
            {
                var savePicker = new FileSavePicker();
                savePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.DocumentsLibrary;

                // Dropdown of file types the user can save the file as
                savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("zip", new List<string>() { ".zip" });
                // Default file name if the user does not type one in or select a file to replace
                savePicker.SuggestedFileName = baseFolderName;

                StorageFile localfile = await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();
                if (localfile == null)
                {
                    return false;
                }

                string pathOfZip = string.Empty;
                StorageFolder destinationfolder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync(baseFolderName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
                if (destinationfolder != null)
                {
                    StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace("PickedFolderToken", destinationfolder);

                    for (int i = 0; i < contentOfFilesWithFileNames.Count; i++)
                    {
                        var item = contentOfFilesWithFileNames.ElementAt(i);
                        string fileNameToCreate = item.Key;
                        string formattedFileName = fileNameToCreate.Replace(",", string.Empty).Replace("/", "-").Replace(":", "-");
                        var file = await destinationfolder.CreateFileAsync(string.Format("{0}.html", formattedFileName), CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
                        var res = await WriteStorageFileAction(file, item.Value);
                    }

                    await Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        string temp = Directory.GetParent(destinationfolder.Path).FullName;
                        pathOfZip = string.Format("{0}\\{1}{2}.zip", temp, baseFolderName, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm"));
                        if (File.Exists(pathOfZip))
                        {
                            File.Delete(pathOfZip);
                        }

                        // Zipping file into the same folder throws exception that its being used by an other process.
                        // So zip to new location.
                        ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(destinationfolder.Path, pathOfZip,
                                CompressionLevel.Optimal, true);
                    });

                    if (localfile != null)
                    {
                        string faToken = StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(localfile);
                        StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(pathOfZip);
                        var storageFolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(localfile.Path); //This line throws the exception.
                        await file.MoveAsync(storageFolder);
                    }

                    await destinationfolder.DeleteAsync();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }

            return false;
        }
```

Update:

Here is the Mainifest Namespaces:

<Package

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
         xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
         xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
         xmlns:desktop4="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/desktop/windows10/4"
         xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
         IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap">
```

I updated the Package Manifest file which looks as follows. but I have a green scribbly under rescap:Capability .

[image: rescap:Capability]

Now the error is as follows:
[image: green scribbly warning]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get a **StorageFolder** object using `StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync` method, then you need to pass a folder path as parameter. The `localfile` object is a **StorageFile** object that you got from a FileSavePicker. The `localfile.Path` represents a location of a file, not a folder. That's why you are having this exception.

For your scenario, if you want to get the parent folder of the file that you've picked, I'd suggest you use [StorageFile.GetParentAsync Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile.getparentasync?view=winrt-22000#windows-storage-storagefile-getparentasync)

**Update:**

It seems that you are picking files that are placed somewhere the UWP app doesn't have permissions to access by default. So the picker could only give you access to the single file but you can't achieve the parent folder because you don't have permission to access the folder.

Please go through [File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) to understand this behavior better.

For such a scenario, if you want to get the parent folder that places somewhere the UWP doesn't have permission to access. using the path will be better. First, you will need to add the `broadFileSystemAccess` capability in the manifest file.

Like this:

```
     <Package
xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap">

<Capabilities>
    <rescap:Capability Name="broadFileSystemAccess" />
</Capabilities>
```

Then, after you've got the `localfile` object, split the path of the `localfile` and you could get the path of the parent folder.

Now you could call `StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync` like this:

```
StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(parentfolderpath)
```

Comment: When i say var storageFolder = await localfile.GetParentAsync(); then its giving a null.

Comment: @nikhil I've updated my answer, please check that.

Comment: I made this code change, when I debug the parentDirectory is C:\Users\Nan\Documents\Test.

 var parentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(localfile.Path);

                        var storageFolder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(parentDirectory);

Comment: I still get Access is Denied. In the Package menifest I see a green scribbly under <rescap:Capability Name="broadFileSystemAccess" /> it says

Comment: "The element 'Capabilities' in namespace 'hap:// schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifesttfoundation/ windows10' has invalid child element 'Capability' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/ manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities' List of possible elements expected: 'CapabilityChoice' i namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/ manifesttfoundation/windows10' as well as 'Capability' in namespace'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/ manifesttuap/windows10' as well as 'Capability' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/ manifesttfoundation/windows10' as ......"

Comment: The app manifest file is as follows.

<Package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
         xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
         xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
         xmlns:desktop4="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/desktop/windows10/4"
         xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
         IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap">

Comment: Within the package element there is a Capabilities section all the way in the end I added. 
<Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer" />
    <rescap:Capability Name="broadFileSystemAccess" />
    <rescap:Capability Name="confirmAppClose" />
  </Capabilities>

Comment: Please see the updated post.

Comment: @nikhil What is the real problem? Can you run your app correctly? Is the access denied exception the real problem?

Comment: Yes that's the real problem. I'm getting the parent directory name without the filename. I added the broadFileSystemAccess in the package manifest capability. Now when I say var storagefolder=await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(parentDirectory) it gives me access is denied.

Comment: Initially without the Package manifest edit if I said localFile.GetParentAsync() it gave me null. Now after adding the package manifest and Changing to GetFolderFromPathAsync(parentFolder). It gives me access is denied in this case.

Comment: Thank you @Roy Li - MSFT it works. I had to enable the File System Privacy Settings for the App.

Comment: Here is a similar post. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54595824/how-to-solve-access-denied-when-using-uwp-getfolderfrompathasync